# Android - Native Facebook app causing invalid_key error?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm working on implanting Facebook in my app. Now I didn't put the Hash Key because I don't want the Single Sign On feature.

I managed to get it it work, but if I have the native Facebook app on my device I get an 'invalid_key error'. If I uninstall the Facebook app it all works fine(logging in, posting on wall...).

Do I have to put the Has Key in order to get my app to work along with the native Facebook app? What's causing this issue?

I really don't want to put the Has Key, simply because I've had too many problems trying to generate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually set a FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH parameter in the authorize call which will opt your application out of SSO.  I've written up the various different solutions here: http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/

That said, I'd definitely try to get the Hash Key working. It's really the better user experience.